# Cookie set for parent domain only works in certain browsers

Tags: vue.js, firefox, cookies, vue-cookies

I have a Vue frontend where I use vue-cookies to set cookie on login.

The following example URLs are used for the application

- client.mydomain.com
- api.mydomain.com

This is the code setting the cookie in Vue

```
    this.$cookies.set(
        'my_jwt',
        response.data.data.token,
        '1d',
        'null',
        mydomain.com
    );
```

CORS is enabled and most things are working fine.

However in certain browsers fetching images from the API fails with 401 because the cookie is not sent with  GET requests that are initiated due to img tags. The API requires a valid JWT for accessing files.

In Chome and Firefox Developer Edition it works fine, but in standard Firefox images are failing.

I also noticed that login in Safari is not working at all (probably due to some related problem).

Would love some input on what could cause this problem.

Comment: Just wondered, what do you see when you visit about:preferences#privacy and then select "manage cookies" or whatever that's called? Which website is listed as having the cookie? The main domain or the sub? Otherwise I don't really have other ideas.

Comment: @NoobTracker The parent domain (mydomain.com) is the one in the issued cookie

Comment: And in browsers where it works? (sorry, I don't have any other ideas)

Comment: @NoobTracker: Completely identical. It seems like it's just treated differently by different browsers.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, but I have no clue what to look at otherwise. But maybe you should add that to your post.